# How to get around "function ends without a return statement" when running `go get` in golang

Tags: go

I am trying to install this Cassandra driver for golang: https://github.com/tux21b/gocql

When I execute `go get https://github.com/tux21b/gocql` I get

```
root@backend:/vagrant# go get tux21b.org/v1/gocql
# tux21b.org/v1/gocql
/usr/lib/go/src/pkg/tux21b.org/v1/gocql/conn.go:280: function ends without a return statement
/usr/lib/go/src/pkg/tux21b.org/v1/gocql/conn.go:359: function ends without a return statement
/usr/lib/go/src/pkg/tux21b.org/v1/gocql/conn.go:407: function ends without a return statement
/usr/lib/go/src/pkg/tux21b.org/v1/gocql/marshal.go:1000: function ends without a return statement
```

How can I manage the package to be installed?

Comment: You are using Go version 1.0. Update to version 1.1.

Comment: @Mostafa You should add that as an answer. I have a feeling it will be a fairly common question :-)

Comment: @Intermernet I thought it’s not actually an answer, but you’re right. It may happen for people who have not upgraded yet. I write an answer.

Comment: Why vote to close it down? This is an actual question that happens for people who have not upgraded their Go yet, but are upgrading or installing a Go package. Exactly the same thing happened for my colleague a few weeks ago. I vote for reopening.

Answer (score 7):

The first thing to do when encountered with this particular compile error is to make sure you have upgraded from version 1.0 of Go to version 1.1 or newer.

The reason is that Go compiler have become smarter in detecting functions that don’t return their expected return values. For example, a function like this:

```
function check(n int) bool {
    if n > 10 {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

would lead to a compile error with Go 1.0, but Go 1.1 can correctly detect that this function always return a value and is OK.